# Screen Goes Blank when Changing to Console

Tags: fedora, tty

Recently I realized that whenever I wanted to change to any of the console windows (Ctrl+Alt+F2 - Ctrl+Alt+F6), my screen simply blanks out and goes into standby due to lack of input from my graphics adapter. This issue was definitely not there on Fedora 31, but I cannot say whether it was in Fedora 32 from the start or started somewhat later. The system is a fresh installation and not an upgrade.

While I can regain control of the computer by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 (GDM greeter screen) or Ctrl+Alt+F7 (graphical environment after being logged in), the change to the plain text console window no longer works.

Running `journalctl -f` with elevated permissions I get the following output (I timed the switch to make it easier to spot in the logs, which is why the timestamps are all with zero-seconds):

```
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "54"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "33"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event8  - Video Bus: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "52"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "92"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "53"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event13 - Corsair CORSAIR HS70 Pro Wireless Gaming Headset Consumer Control: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event12 - HID 0557:2419: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "59"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event16 - HID 0557:2419: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "57"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "55"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "48"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event11 - Logitech MX Ergo: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "57"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event3  - ckb1: Corsair Gaming K95 RGB PLATINUM Keyboard vKB: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (**) Option "fd" "55"
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) event4  - ckb1: Corsair Gaming K95 RGB PLATINUM Keyboard vM: device removed
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:77
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:1
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:80
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Sep 24 12:24:00 computer_name_here /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4285]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Sep 24 12:24:15 computer_name_here kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
Sep 24 12:24:15 computer_name_here kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x37
```

The last two lines are the result of me pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after a short time in the feeble (and futile) attempt to revive the screen.

Suspecting graphics driver issues, I may need to mention that I have a GeForce GTX 1080 using the following drivers:

```
$ sudo dnf list installed "*nvidia*"
Installed Packages
akmod-nvidia.x86_64                          3:450.66-1.fc32    @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
kmod-nvidia-5.8.10-200.fc32.x86_64.x86_64    3:450.66-1.fc32    @@commandline             
kmod-nvidia-5.8.4-200.fc32.x86_64.x86_64     3:450.66-1.fc32    @@commandline             
kmod-nvidia-5.8.7-200.fc32.x86_64.x86_64     3:450.66-1.fc32    @@commandline             
nvidia-settings.x86_64                       3:450.66-1.fc32    @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia.x86_64                   3:450.66-2.fc32    @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda-libs.x86_64         3:450.66-2.fc32    @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-kmodsrc.x86_64           3:450.66-2.fc32    @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.x86_64              3:450.66-2.fc32    @rpmfusion-nonfree-updates
```

The kmod packages are not manually installed by me, but must have been installed through the akmod package when installing a new kernel.

GRUB starts my installation using the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1 rd.lvm.lv=Samsung_SSD_970_PRO/system rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on"
```

Does anyone have a solution and/or can hint me to the appropriate file to verify its contents? If more logs or information is required, I am happy to supply it.

**UPDATE (to address comment):**

```
$ lsmod | grep -i nvidia
nvidia_drm             57344  8
nvidia_modeset       1187840  14 nvidia_drm
nvidia_uvm           1138688  0
nvidia              19742720  607 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        262144  5 drm_vram_helper,ast,nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   626688  20 drm_kms_helper,drm_vram_helper,ast,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,i915,ttm
```

Comment: Could you please post the output of lsmod | grep nvidia

Comment: @MC68020, done.

Comment: This happens with NVIDIA binary drivers for some people. Please ask here as well: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, Thanks!  I may do that.  When you state that it happens to some people, is there a general cause, which can be verified/excluded or is this issue too complex to find even a single denominator to check for?  So far, I also checked [Blank Screen on Console Login and Startx - GeForce GTX 1650 - Driver 440.82](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-blank-screen-on-console-login-and-startx-geforce-gtx-1650-driver-440-82/122376), but connecting a second display to my graphics adapter did not solve it for me.

Comment: I've no idea why it happens but this forum is probably the only place where this issue could be reported and resolved though no one will tell you an ETA. For instance I reported an I2C bug seven years ago and it was fixed just a week ago.

Comment: On forums, I never expect any ETA.  Only that if I get a response, that it allows me to troubleshoot further.  Thanks again!